# Hibernate Validator: Only Return Child Name in Path for Property Paths

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

**Setup**

Say I have a request like:

```
{
   "parent": {
       "child": null
   }
}
```

If I'm mapping it to a bean like this:

```
public class Parent {

    @NotBlank private final String child;

    @JsonCreator
    public Parent(
            @JsonProperty("child") String child) {
        this.child = child;
    }
}
```

Given the request above if I annotate my Parent bean (named `parent`) with a @Valid annotation, I end up getting a violation constraint with the property path set to `"parent.child"`.

**Question**

What I'm curious about is if there is a simply way to have just the child property name in the property path, so it just resolves to `"child"`?

I realize I could write a custom validator for this, but I feel like that would be a bit overkill here. Is there any built-in way to accomplish this with Hibernate Validator?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve this automatically in Hibernate Validator.

Couldn't you pass the `Parent` object itself to the validation engine (instead of some wrapper object you seem to have)? Otherwise, you could implement some kind of post-processing which returns the first element from field/path names in the response sent to clients.